# Using the $_GET variable

Tags: php

I need a little help with using $_GET variables if possible. Right now I am using them to load different parts of my website when needed but I can't figure out how to clear the screen as if a new page were being loaded when the $_GET variable is set. I was wondering if it is possibele.

As an example say I have a sports categories page which lists all the sport available on the website, In the controller I have this piece of code which activates when the user clicks on football in the list of sports:

```
if (isset($_GET['football'])) 
        {  
            .... 
        }
```

So at the moment all of the football information is displayed along with all of the category information. Is there a way to remove the category information and just have the sports info there without using javascript?

Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Use POST or URL rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that when the user clicks "Football" a new HTTP request is done, then you can have:

`if(!isset($_GET["football"])) ...
{
    // Code to display categories
}`

If you don't have another HTTP request, then you will have to do it with Javascript, hidding the element that contains the category list.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

The $_GET method is usually used to retrieve variables from a webpage's URL.
Although it could be populated in other ways i believe.
To clean it just unset it. Like so:

```
unset($_GET["football"]);
```

Also, if you are using it to retrieve data from you URL you can just refresh the page without the variables on it like so
Original URL: www.stackoverflow.com?id=10
Refresh it as empty www.stackoverflow.com

With those 2 methods, you should be able to clear your gets from any data. Use accordingly to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the querystring key to differentiate, use a common key (in my example `category` ) and change the value, eg `http://example.com/page.php?category=football`.

Then you can perform a switch on the value, and show either the category content, or the list of categories if no specific category is requested:

```
$category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : 'none';

switch($castegory){
    case 'football':
        //show football content
        break;
    case 'golf':
        //show golf content
        break;
    default:
       //show list of categories
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an `else` statement. Or otherwise, you need to write your code in such a way that categories are only displayed if `$_GET['football']` is not set.